# Javascript: Is there something like sessionStorage or localStorage for one page only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a website using ASP.NET MVC and HTML/JavaScript.
On this website I have a page with a data form which contains multiple text fields, comboboxes, datetime pickers and other controls (some of them are from the jQuery UI extension) where the user can enter data.

Now I have the requirement that the entered data should not get lost when refreshing the page as currently all fields in the form become blank when the page is refreshed.

I have already implemented a solution which stores everything the user enters in the sessionStorage and restores it when the user refreshes the page. However, the sessionStorage is not ideal for this purpose because the data will even get restored when the user navigates to a completely different page on the website and then navigates back to the page that contains the data form.

Is there any way to store data via JavaScript that works just like the sessionStorage (or localStorage) but is automatically cleared when the user navigates to a different page? If not, is there at least a simple way how I could manually clear the sessionStorage whenever the user navigates to another page?

Comment: Just save it under a key with the page name in session/local storage?

Comment: @VLAZ But that way it would still be restored when the user navigates to another page on my website and then comes back to the page with the data form, wouldn't it? The only solution that came to my mind so far involves clearing the sessionStorage on all other pages of my website but that just seems like a dumb solution.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: I think u may choose a different approach, you may save the values into a temp row on the background (on server side) while the user is writing the values. An Ajax call will work. When page refresh happens, you can check if there is a non-completed form or not (on server). Navigating to a different page can also be handled using ajax. An ajax call can delete the incomplete row on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle document ready event in your layout page, then you can check by your page URL.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location.href != 'your url') {
            // reset all data
        }
        else {
            // restore data from local storage
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and does not require manually adding code for clearing the sessionStorage to every single page on the website individually!

Answer (score 1):

This function will be called on url change.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
 // reset the data
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it seems like that function/event does not get called when I navigate to another page on the site. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? I do not see any errors in the console and it does not make a difference if I put that code directly in my JavaScript code or run it for example in $(document).ready. Is this supported by all current browsers or could it be a compatibility issue?

Comment: I think this could help you.

    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    //write your code
    };